# flutter - percent indicator progressColor

Tags: flutter, indicator

i use [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) package. I wrapped CircularPercentIndicator with Gesturedetetor, i increase start parameter every touch onTap function.

Every time I tap to increase the numeric value by one, the CircularPercentIndicator color starts over. For example; My start parameter is 8 and once I touched it, my start parameter is 9, but the CircularPercentIndicator starts from 0 to 9.

> int start = 0;

```
GestureDetector(
          child: CircularPercentIndicator(
            radius: 100.0,
            lineWidth: 13.0,
            animation: true,
            percent: start.toDouble() / 100,
            center: Text(
              start.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            footer: const Text(
              "Sales this week",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0),
            ),
            circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
            progressColor: Colors.purple,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            start = start + 1;
            setState(() {});
            print(start.toString());
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the plugin source code, that is how the plugin is developed, it updates the progress, and runs the _animation.forward(),  which will make the animation start from 0 - currentProgress.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. There is a property like below.

```
animateFromLastPercent: true
```